# Domain forwarding and DNS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, domain-name

In Google domains I have a main domain at examplesite.com
and a secondary domain example-site.com that is forwarded to main's URL:

```
Domain (example-site.com) forwards to
https://www.examplesite.com

Redirect Type
Permanent redirect (301)

Path forwarding
Do not forward path

SSL
SSL On
```

What's confusing me are leftover DNS entries for example-site.com.

```
ftp  CNAME 1h  example-site.com.    
imap CNAME 55m imap.secureserver.net.   
mail CNAME 55  mpop.secureserver.net.   
pop  CNAME 1h  pop.secureserver.net.
smtp CNAME 55m smtp.secureserver.net.
```

It seems like main this was main domain once (years ago) and it was dumped in favor of examplesite.com. Can I delete all DNS entries for this redirected domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those entries read as follows:

- ftp.example-site.com will load example-site.com
- imap.example-site.com will load imap.secureserver.net
- mail.example-site.com will load mpop.secureserver.net
- pop.example-site.com will load pop.secureserver.net
- smtp.example-site.com will load smtp.secureserver.net

The first one you might want to redirect to examplesite.com, assuming the ftp subdomain is still relevant. The other ones, you *might* want to set up CNAMEs at examplesite.com to do the same. Those 4 entries appear to be configured for folks to use the Godaddy email services but by using your old domain; likely so they don't have to remember the GoDaddy URLs. If they use SSL/TLS connections for their email however (which they should), they'll probably end up with certificate errors when using those addresses because the GoDaddy server certificates won't have your domain listed.

Comment: There is nothing on old domain, AFAIK. No hosting, no files, no relevant mail. It's only that second domain(example-site.com) is redirected at main ( one and only) website (examplesite.com) now. That should mean that mail and ftp entries for example-site.com should be safe to delete?

Comment: It's a question of whether anyone is still trying to use those DNS entries and whether you're concerned about any interruption to that service. You could perform a check with your logs to see what URL people are accessing or send out a notification that the domain is being deprecated. Otherwise just nuke it.